# JavaScript for loop closure issue

Tags: javascript, closures

I am adding all categories after ticking them to true if they exists in selected categories of `result` but it combines previous categories results with current one. I tried closure but it doesn't give me fresh object. **Check out [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4gnwmrcv/).**

```
var allCatsResult = [{"id":1},{"id":2}, {"id":3}, ... ];

var catsArray = [1, 2] // Array of ids from allCatsResult 
var result = [
                {"id":1, selectedCategories:[{"id":1},{"id":2}]},
                {"id":2, selectedCategories:[{"id":4},{"id":5}]},
                ... 
             ];

for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    var tmp = allCatsResult; // tried to add function form here didn't work
    for (var k = 0; k < results[i].selectedCategories.length; k++) {
        var index = catsArray.indexOf(results[i].selectedCategories[k].category_id);        
        if(index !== -1) {
            tmp[index].ticked =  true;
        }
    }               
    results[i].categories = tmp;
}
```

Above code gives combined result for ticked = true for all categories in each result.

Comment: should it not be ```results.length``` as that is the name of your array?

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald fixed typo.

Comment: where is the closure? what the result should be?

Comment: @webduvet : each result should have all categories but for selected categories there should be `ticked = true`

Comment: @charlietfl : please see fiddle result and inspect categories in each object.

Comment: I see some with ticked = false, really not clear what issue is. Code that isn't working properly is not always a good substitute for a proper problem statement

Comment: @charlietfl : code is not working properly thats why I have asked this question. Code should work as it is written but it isn't.

Comment: And what exactly is it supposed to do? Where does it differ from what you want it to do? Where are the expected results? There have been lots of views of this post but nobody else is understanding it either or you would have answers

Comment: @charlietfl please check above comments I already explained what should be results.

Comment: `Above code gives combined result for ticked = true for all categories ` no it doesn't I see many `false`

Comment: @charlietfl have you even tried to check fiddle result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to copy/clone the array of objects, or you're manipulating the original. There are a few ways apparently. I chose the following:

```
var tmp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(allCatsResult));
```

This will create a new array of objects in `tmp`, and it will correctly only modify the clone.

Comment: why? `indexOf()` returns `-1` if not found.

Comment: I never get null so I will just skip this one.

Comment: @Shreejibawa I hope I can make up my past mistake with this